# How can I combine same-named columns into one in a pandas dataframe so all the columns are unique?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [268]: dft.head()                                                                                 
Out[268]: 
ticker     BYND           UBER      UBER     UBER  ...        ZM       ZM          BYND       ZM
0       analyst         worlds      uber  revenue  ...   company   owning           pet   things
1        moskow           apac      note     uber  ...       try   things  humanization    users
2        growth  anheuserbusch    growth   target  ...   postipo  unicorn      products  revenue
3         stock           kong  analysts   raised  ...  software  revenue        things  million
4        target    uberbeating     stock   rising  ...  earnings  million          pets   direct

[5 rows x 500 columns]

In [269]: dft.columns.unique()                                                                       
Out[269]: Index(['BYND', 'UBER', 'LYFT', 'SPY', 'WORK', 'CRWD', 'ZM'], dtype='object', name='ticker')
```

How do I combine the the columns so there is only a single unique column name for each ticker?

Comment: How do you decide which name to choose?

Comment: Added the names: 'BYND', 'UBER', 'LYFT', 'SPY', 'WORK', 'CRWD', 'ZM'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try making a copy of the column you wish to join then extend the first column with the copy you have.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

First convert the all columns name into one case either in lower or upper case so that there is no miss-match in header case.

```
def merge_(df):
  '''Return the data-frame with columns with the same lowercase'''

  # Get the list of unique columns in lowercase
  columns = set(map(str.lower,df.columns))
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((len(df),len(columns))),columns=columns)

  # Merging the matching columns
  for col in df.cloumns:
    df1[col.lower()] += df[col] # words are in str format so '+' will concatenate 


  return df1
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when i run on my dataframe: ```AttributeError: 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'reindex_like'
```